# Refactoring Repeated if Statements

Tags: python, if-statement, refactoring

My code looks like this:

```
var1 = do_something_1()
if param == 'A':
    var1 = do_something_A_1()

var2 = do_something_2(var1)
if param == 'B':
    var2 = do_something_B_1()

var3 = do_something_3(var2)
if param == 'A':
    var3 = do_something_A_2()

var4 = do_something_4(var3)
if param == 'A':
    var4 = do_something_A_3()
```

I was wondering whether there's a way to refactor the `if` statements in this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a ternary expression + tuple assignment?

```
var1, var2, var3, var4, var5 = \
    (do_something_1(), do_something_2(), do_something_3(), do_something_4(), do_something_5()) if param == 'A' 
    else \ 
    (do_something_A_1(), do_something_A_2(), do_something_A_3(), do_something_A_4(), do_something_A_5())
```

it not only saves you evaluating things you'll be throwing away (assuming you're not interested in side effects), it also saves you reevaluating the same expression too.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace this

```
var1 = do_something_1()
if param == 'A':
    var1 = do_something_A_1()
```

with

```
var1 =  do_something_A_1() if param == 'A' else do_something_1()
```

Comment: You seem to be mixing up c-type ternaries with Python's.

Comment: :-) Nope, halfway there. Try again.

Comment: mmm... I guess I need an explanation than, just checked it with https://repl.it and everything seems fine.

Comment: It had the form ``... if ... : ...`` when I commented. The ``else`` appeared after it. Anyway, it's fine now, and I'm removing the downvote (although I'm tempted to keep it for your using Ruby [just kidding]).

Comment: Oh. yeah. I missed that at first, but reedited just a second after commenting)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this (for python 2.5 and greater).

```
var1 = do_something_A_1() if param == 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about if you clearly spell out in each of the three possible case, like this:

```
def func(param):
    """
    :param 'A' or 'B' or 'C'
    """
    if param == 'A':
        var1 = do_something_1()
        var1 = do_something_A_1()
        var2 = do_something_2(var1)
        var3 = do_something_3(var2)
        var3 = do_something_A_2()
        var4 = do_something_4(var3)
        var4 = do_something_A_3()
        var5 = do_something_5(var4)

    elif param == 'B':
        var1 = do_something_1()
        var2 = do_something_2(var1)
        var2 = do_something_B_1()
        var3 = do_something_3(var2)
        var4 = do_something_4(var3)
        var5 = do_something_5(var4)

    elif param == 'C':
        var1 = do_something_1()
        var2 = do_something_2(var1)
        var3 = do_something_3(var2)
        var4 = do_something_4(var3)
        var5 = do_something_5(var4)

    return var5
```

Comment: For your code, is there a way to avoid duplication?